# Elementor Contact Form Submit button has empty class

Tags: css, html

I have a contact form here: https://www.vztplzen.cz/kontaktni-formular/ It is built using Elementor’s Contact Form widget. The submit button has empty class:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit-contact-b1e59dc" class="">ODESLAT ZPRÁVU</button>
```

How can I assign a class to the element? My clients needs that for some GA/GTM magic. I can’t find it anywhere in the settings and I didn’t manage to find any documentation on it.

I tried disabling a CSS/JS minification plugin, clearing the cache and regenerating Elementor’s CSS, but neither helped.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add below code in your JS file and replace the class demo with class name you want to add. I have made this code as per the structure in the URL you have shared above.

```
jQuery("#content-form-b1e59dc").find("button").addClass("demo");
```